# Create A Temporary Table In PL-SQL Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

This is probably something silly that I'm over looking.

I have this code in a trigger. The full trigger is here: (There's more code above this code) http://pastebin.com/KcBZdEmt

```
CREATE TABLE ApprList AS 
SELECT
U.*
FROM pmm$PmmReleaseRequest R
INNER JOIN dbo$ManagedEntity ME
ON ME.ManagedEntityID = R.ManagedSystemID
INNER JOIN dbo$SmartRuleAssetCache SRC
ON SRC.AssetID = ME.AssetID
INNER JOIN dbo$UserGroup_SmartRule_Role GSR
ON GSR.SmartRuleId = SRC.SmartRuleId
AND GSR.RoleId IN (2,3)
INNER JOIN dbo$AppUser_UserGroup UG
ON UG.GroupID = GSR.UserGroupId
AND UG.UserID <> R.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo$AppUser U ON UG.UserID = U.UserID
WHERE R.ReleaseRequestID = ReleaseRequestID
AND U.UserID <> RequestorUserID;
```

On the folling line:

```
CREATE TABLE ApprList AS
```

I get:

```
Error(111,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge
```

It's probably best to take a peak at the pastebin file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't create table inside trigger without dynamic SQL. You need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE....'`

Comment: You can't even do it dynamically inside a trigger because that would implicitly commit, which isn't allowed. Your title also says you're creating a temporary table, but your code is for a permanent table. Oracle doesn't have local temporary tables; you need a global temporary table, as kevinsky shows.

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix DDL and DML statements together without using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. However the whole idea of creating a table in a trigger while perfectly fine in SQL Server is not a best practice in Oracle.  Use a global temporary table instead.
Create this table and then insert into it from the trigger.Something like this sample

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE YourSchema.Yourtable
-- Create table

( 
  pk_id           NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
  company         VARCHAR2(20 VARCHAR2) not null,
  voucher_type    VARCHAR2(3 VARCHAR2) not null,
  voucher_no      NUMBER(10) not null,
  year_period_key NUMBER not null
)
on commit PRESERVE rows;
```

Comment: It isn't just not best practice; you can't commit inside a trigger, so can't even do dynamic DDL, since that implicitly commits. You'd get an ORA-04092 when the trigger fires. (I guess you could have an autonomous procedure but... no, lets not go there...)